# How to open Swagger / index by default instead of Index.chtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

When i start a project (.Net Core MVC), Index.chtml opens as usual. How to open Swagger interface by default.

I have default route like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using couple of ways:

1. Open `launchsettings.json` file and change the value of the `applicationUrl` parameter to swagger url.

Or

2. Add this route to RouteConfig.cs

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "swagger_root",
        routeTemplate: "",
        defaults: null,
        constraints: null,
        handler: new RedirectHandler((message => message.RequestUri.ToString()), "swagger"));
```

Or

3. change `Launch browser` in project properties, Debug tab:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways you could achieve this:

1. Change the Home Index action to HTTP redirect to your Swagger UI
2. You can update the your Debug panel of the project's properties in Visual Studio to launch the Swagger UI page's URL instead of the root of your application.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Debug pane]